# Do these sentence have adjective of verb 3 instead of passive simple present tense (buried, closed, defeated, published)?

Tags: grammar, verbs, adjectives, passive-voice

- Most of my family are buried near my home.
- The case is dismissed.
- I am defeated. Nothing left to look forward to and nothing left to hold on to.
- Your first question is published.

What I have realized with these sentences is that they don't explain a general case but explain a situation. For instance, *my father is buried here* doesn't mean I bury my father everyday or once a week but shows the current situation of my dad i.e., he is buried and dead.

When I say "the case is dismissed" it is not like we dismiss this case generally or often but it explains the situation of the case i.e., it is no longer a valid case. So I thought that these four words (buried, dismissed, defeated, published) are not verbs in the form of passive simple present tense but they are adjectives in the form of verb 3.

My question is "am I right?". If I am right, can we use almost all the verbs in English like this i.e., by creating adjective in the form of verb 3 and use them like in these sentences?

Comment: I don't know what 'verb 3' is, but yes, they are participles used as adjectives, implying that the action has happened to them.

Comment: They are the remains of deceased passive constructions, leaving only their results as adjectives. This kind of adjective is very common in English, and needs to be distinguished from real passives, which can transform back to active. Don't know what you mean about Verb 3.

Comment: You are right that these are not passive, though close. *The door is closed* falls into that class, along with *the day is done*. *I see the door is closed by the wind each time it blows* is passive.